# Basic question on histogram plotting in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

can anybody, please, help me to understand the ouput of this code?? I want simply to obtain an histogram with the specified bin edges and bin frequency values.

```
edges=np.array([106,150,212,300,425,600,850,875])
freq=np.array([0.02,0.15,16.55,41.19,27.18,11.72,1.97])
plt.hist(freq,bins=edges)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

`plt.hist(x)` *computes* and then draws a histogram of `x`. Your data is already in histogram form. Simply plot it with:

```
mids = 0.5 * (edges[:-1] + edges[1:]) # Midpoints of the histogram bins
plt.bar(mids, freq, 40) # Draw a bar chart with bars of width 40
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with with @Seb about the data already being in histogram form, but could we still use `plt.hist()` by passing the `edges` as both the data and the bins and pass `freq` as the weights:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

edges = [106, 150, 212, 300, 425, 600, 850, 875]
freq = [0.02, 0.15, 16.55, 41.19, 27.18, 11.72, 1.97, 0]

plt.hist(edges, bins=edges, weights=freq)
plt.show()
```

[image]

As @Seb's `plt.bar()` approach doesn't visually emphasize the width of the buckets:

[image]